# Undecimated DWT vs. CWT. In what cases is one preferable over another?

Tags: wavelet

Talking about undecimated [DWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform) let's focus here on [SWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_wavelet_transform) algorithm.

SWT is said to be:

- numerically more stable due to Mallat algorithm. And the inverse operation is capable of returning the original signal which is not the case with [CWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_wavelet_transform)
- SWT is computationally faster than CWT

On the other hand:

- SWT works on dyadic scale while with CWT you can choose any scale sampling

Are there any other factors supporting the choise of one or another alternative?

Comment: When difference do you make between "non-orthogonal" and CWT?  In "DWT produces orthogonal decomposition", how do you link that to the title "In what cases (bi)orthogonal wavelet"

Comment: sorry, I've mixed two questions here in a confusing manner. I'll separate them

Comment: The questions are clearer now. I can answer them later in the week, if nobody else does that

Comment: @LaurentDuval: and the week has passed…

Comment: I should say that I do not fully understand the exact need, and some of the given assertions, eg "SWT works on dyadic scale", can be debated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any other factors supporting the choice of one or another alternative?

- possibility to use almost any wavelet shape (and associated sampling) or signal-matched: in favor of the CWT
- possible parallelization in cycle-spinning form: in favor of SWT
- tunable redundancy factor: in favor of the CWT
- possibility to derive sharp signal/noise estimators for denoising: in favor of SWT
- geometrical extensions (direction, shear, anisotropy) in higher dimension: in favor of the CWT